# Implementation of query pattern error while retriving the data from LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql

I have a stored procedure for searching from multiple tables as

```
`ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[rdsp_Srchfld]
(
@strFldlst as nvarchar(max),
@strTblnm as nvarchar(max),
@intSrchStyle as int,
@strcond1 as nvarchar(250),
@strCond2 as nvarchar(250)=null,
@strCond3 as nvarchar(300)
)
AS
BEGIN 
declare @strSql as varchar(7000)


--Process
set @strSql = 'select Distinct ' + @strFldlst  + ' from ' + @strTblnm 
IF @intSrchStyle = 0
BEGIN
    SET @strSql = @strSql + ' where ' + @strcond1  + ' = ' + '''' + @strCond2 + '''' + ' order by ' + '' + @strcond3 + ''
END
ELSE IF @intSrchStyle = 1
BEGIN
    SET @strSql = @strSql + ' where ' + @strcond1 + ' like ' + '''' + @strCond2 + '%' + '''' + ' order by ' + '' + @strcond3 + ''
END



ELSE IF @intSrchStyle = 2 
BEGIN
    SET @strSql = @strSql + ' where ' + @strcond1  + ' like ' + '''' + '%' + @strCond2 + '%' + '''' + ' order by ' + '' + @strcond3 + ''
END

EXEC (@strSql)
END`
```

and passing the parameters from LINQ to Sql as

```
var rslt = from srch in custDC.rdsp_Srchfld(fldName, tblName, srchType, cond1, cond2, cond3) select srch;
```

Now I tried to build my programe, I am getting error as

```
Error   1   Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'int'.  'Select' not found.
```

Why I am getting the error and how can I implement it.

Comment: Why do dynamic SQL in an SP when you are using Linq-To-Sql? This approach combines all the danger and inflexibility of SPs while avioding any of the benefits. If used right, for the right reasons, they can be fast and secure.

Comment: What query plan could be compiled for this SP?

Comment: @Jodrell: to retrieve the data from multiple tables by passing tablename and field names as parameters.

Comment: Which tables and field names? The first ones you use. I think you'll be lucky and no plan will be stored for the SP. Have a look at the "Common Cases when to (Not) Use Dynamic SQL" in sommarskog link in my answer. http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Common_cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not do this. Abandon your approach now.

Start by reading this, http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Think about why Linq-to-SQL was created. Take a look at its successor EF.

Then make a model for your database from an established SQL Server supporting [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). Then use the model to give you nice type checked code. Let the model do the dymanic SQL for you. If you have a special requirement or situation that the ORM does not cope with. Then consider writing a special SP to deal with it.

---

If you are going to persist with your approach at least understand what an [SQL Injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) is. Learn about [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188001.aspx) and use it.

---

If Linq-to-SQL can't get your dynamic SQL right, for whatever reason, it makes more sense to build the statement on the client/application layer, not in an SP. Look at the [ExecuteQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executequery.aspx) and [ExecuteCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand.aspx) methods of [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx). If an ORM is too much, using vanilla ADO.Net and an [`SqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) has merit.

Comment: Linq2SQL evolved into EF is quite a strong statement.

Comment: @leppie, true, natural selection never stops.